# Which is best source to store Tree sturcuture for swift-ios?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i have big trees. which i want to store in app.can anyone suggest which is best storage among this Core data ,sqlite ,json ,xml ? and how can i store tree?.i also attached screen shot for demo-tree which type of trees i wanted to store.[image]

Comment: Don't go with XML in iOS. Either use JSON or coredata for better performance.

Comment: can you tell me how to do with core data?

Comment: @JayPatel: Check out this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial for core data basic.

Answer (score 4):

You should use coreData.
Your coreData Structure should be as shown as below images.
[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Here you can modify the relationship as per your requirements. I just designed the relationship as per the Graph Structure where many nodes are connected with other many nodes i.e. Many parents many Children.

As per your TREE structure just change the relationship from Many Parent Many Children to One Parent Many Children. That's it.

Comment: you created entity for every node.i have approximately 5600 nodes. so, is it good way to create entity for every node?

Comment: Yes this is a betterWay, even its easy to deal with Core data and you can insert update delete entities easily in single line.

Answer (score 2):

Core data should be the 1st preference to store the hierarchical data as that will help in reading the entire object hierarchy without much of loops and nested queries to fetch the data. If you are already not using core data in your app, JSON is the next recommended approach to store hierarchical tree data structure. You can use any object mapper `SwiftyJson` or `AlmofireObjectMapper` to read the JSON and populate the nested array with tree data.